# How to use ng-repeat correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So
this is my json file

```js
{
 "title" : "My skills",
 "webStack" : [
  "HTML5",
  "CSS3",
  "JavaScript",
  "jQuery / AngularJS",
  "SASS / Stylus",
  "Bootstrap / Pure CSS"
 ],
}
```

and this is my html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="skillsController">
 <h1>{{skills.title}}</h1>
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in skills.webStack">
   {{skills.webStack.item}}
  </li>
 </ul>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
   myApp.controller('skillsController', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('skills.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log('this is data:',data);
    $scope.skills = data;
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but in browser I can see only an empty list
how I must to correct use ng-repeat?
please, say, what I must to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `{{skills.webStack.item}}` to `{{item}}`.

In your `ng-repeat` you typed this:
 `<li ng-repeat="item in skills.webStack">`

So, basically, you are saying:

- For each `item` in the collection `skills.webStack` I want to print the `item` itself

Comment: Just to note that the expression `ng-repeat="item in skills.webStack"` simply creates a child scope for each iteration which now has a member named item, which can be bound as any other scope member.

Comment: and right use `ng-repeat="item in skills.webStack track by $index"`